# How to add new column in sql server 2008 using C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

i have three columns in my sql table Id Name and Address

now i want to add another column by using c# code

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you describe what issues you are having doing this? At the moment, it's unclear exactly what you want us to do. See [ask] for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command to add a new table,

```
ALTER table_name 
ADD
column_name nvarchar(50)
```

The above command would alter the table `table_name` and would add another column to it with name `column_name` of `nvarchar` type with 50 characters size. You can execute the above command using an `SqlCommand` object on an `SqlConnection` object.

For more, please refer and read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190238.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).